# Email addresses showing next to contact name

Tags: contacts

I moved to a new gmail account. I have set it up on my Samsung S6. However, now when searching through text messages or contacts email addresses are being show next to the contact name. I have tried everything from unsyncing, restarting phone, removing the new gmail account and setting it back up. I have display only phone contacts which does not work since I have everything saved under the gmail. It is very annoying to see email addresses next to contact names when you're sending text. In general it is very annoying to see email address next to the persons name even under contacts. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I finally broke down and deleted the contacts that showed email addresses next to the contact name. Re-entered that contact and saved again and that fixed the problem. Not sure why, only after syncing the new gmail, it showed that way.

Answer (score 0):

I refused to delete my contacts and history, so I figured it out. Go online to the email that you synced or just created, click the menu button, then click contacts. Somehow all the contacts that got messed up have been edited to the 'last name' being the email. That's why it shows up after the name. So just edit those contacts to have the correct last name or no last name. It worked for me so I hope this helps!